# How to select the correct date in the same column when data in different rows are equal

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have the following problem with my data on a DB2 database. I want to create an overview when a machine was used for a project with a begin and end date.

The following data is available:

```
||Machine name||Description||Project||Start date|
|Mach1|DB2_AIX|Team_1_PERS|TEST_1|07-03-2017|
|Mach1|DB2_AIX|Team_1_PERS|TEST_1|16-03-2017|
|Mach1|DB2_AIX|Team_1_PERS|TEST_1|24-04-2017|
|Mach1|DB2_AIX|Team_1_PERS|TEST_1|07-05-2017|
|Mach1|DB2_AIX|Team_1_PERS|TEST_2|13-05-2016|
|Mach1|DB2_AIX|Team_1_PERS|TEST_1|22-05-2017|
|Mach1|DB2_AIX|Team_1_PERS|TEST_1|12-06-2017|
```

The result that I'm looking for is:

```
|Machine name||Description||Project||Start date||Last date|
|Mach1|DB2_AIX|Team_1_PERS|TEST_1|07-03-2017|07-05-2017|
|Mach1|DB2_AIX|Team_1_PERS|TEST_2|13-05-2016|13-05-2017|
|Mach1|DB2_AIX|Team_1_PERS|TEST_1|22-05-2017|12-06-2017|
```

Does anybody have an idea how to create this result with a statement?

Comment: Your results seem to depend on the ordering of the rows in the table.  However, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so you need a column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: Your question is about a start date AND end date but the end date is not shown in your result. Could you clarify this please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic [gaps-and-islands](/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) problem, and the standard solutions will work just fine:

```
WITH Grouped_Run AS (SELECT name, description, project, test, executedOn,
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY executedOn) -  
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name, description, project, test ORDER BY executedOn) AS groupingId
                     FROM Machine)

SELECT name, description, project, test, MIN(executedOn) as testStart
FROM Grouped_Run
GROUP BY name, description, project, test, groupingId
ORDER BY testStart
```

<kbd>[Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fc3c6b/5/0)</kbd>

(it's a little unclear if the group is going to be the whole row, but that's adjustable)

....will produce the results you're looking for.
Note that depending on what specific version you're on, there may be other/faster ways to achieve these results.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you're trying to get the first and last of "Start date". Write a GROUP BY query with MIN(Start date) and another with MAX(Start date) then union the results. You'll have to select DISTINCT or do another GROUP BY to eliminate the duplicates that will occur when there's only one date.